# Docker installation failed and has left a broken, irremovable apt package

Tags: apt, package-management, docker, software-uninstall

Context: I'm using pop os 22.04

I have tried installing docker via the shell script download method:

```
$ sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

This failed with the message

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: b2e29ef7a9a89840d2333637f7d1900a83e7153f
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Now when I try to use `apt update` i get this error:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease          
Hit:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease             
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease   
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease 
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm InRelease   
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 108.138.199.73 443]
Hit:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

I tried uninstalling it via apt, but it doesn't recognize docker or any of its name variations.

How do I safely remove the files of the incomplete package I have downloaded?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu site, and you're using Pop OS, but has added a Debian repo to your computer. Something is seriously mixed up here...

Comment: I was hoping the distro was similar enough to ubuntu to qualify

Comment: I would assume Pop OS can use the corresponding Ubuntu repo's, but I'm not sure since I don't use Pop OS.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question wasn't on-topic in the first place, but this answer might reasonably be useful to an ubuntu user:

The problem wasn't with any individual file i had downloaded, it was that the installation added https://download.docker.com/linux/debian to the list of sources of my package manager, and the error occurred because it was checking for incompatible debian releases. After removing the link from my sources list `apt update` has resumed working correctly.

Comment: "*incompatible debian releases*" ?  Bookworm hasn't been released yet  (it's like *kinetic* in the Ubuntu world)